# Which of the following is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses, word-order

Which of the following questions are correct according to the grammar, and why?

> 1. When will **be** the results declared?
> 2. When will the results **be** declared?

Does this hold to all future perfect tenses?

Answer (score 1):

1 is not correct and 2 is correct.

The reason is this is using 'will' as a modal verb in a question and the word order in that case is **modal + subject + main verb**.

See this link for more information:

http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/learn-english/grammar/verbs-modals1/